# shuffle order of labels swift / Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working on a quiz app and I have 3 labels who will show the answers. How can I shuffle the order of the labels on the screen to avoid having the right answer always at the same place?

I have all my answers stored in an array and I'm displaying them like that

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstAnswer: UILabel!



@IBOutlet weak var secondAnswer: UILabel!



@IBOutlet weak var thirdAnswer: UILabel!
```

Comment: let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1..<30)

and have a logic like 

if the randomint is multiple of 2 then assign the right answer label1 as first choice

else if randomint is multiple of 3 then  assign the right answer to second choice

If randomint is a prime number assign the right answer  to third choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1..<30)`

and have a logic like

```
if the randomint %% 2 == 0 { firstAnswer.text = right_answer}

else if randomint %% 3 == 0 { secondAnswer.text = right_answer}

else { thirdAnswer.text = right_answer}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to shuffle your labels. If you have your possible answers in let's say an array like that:

```
var answers = ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3"]
```

You can shuffle the elements of the array by calling function `shuffle()` of `Array`, before you set the `text` properies of your `UILabel`s:

```
answers.shuffle()
```